# How to let the user to edit the custom user model details in the user dashboard and update it in the model in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am having edit profile template and I wrote view for letting the user to edit the account but I am not getting the form even I wrote the url and view correctly can you please help me out how to let the user edit user model in the front end
my views.py:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modsy:account'))
```

Forms.py:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    template_name='edit_profile'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password'
        )

    else:
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request,'edit_profile.html')
```

I am only getting the submit button in editprofile page but form is not coming can you please say what mistake I had did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling only for `POST` request only but not for `GET`.Also here your form name is `EditProfileForm` not `UserChangeForm` so change your view like this:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modsy:account'))
    else:
         form = EditProfileForm()
    return render(request,'Your_template',{'form':form})
```

Comment: name 'EditProfileForm' is not defined
getting this error

Comment: Yes I got that I am able to change email but in the place of password iam not getting anything can you help me

Comment: No password set. Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using this form. getting this message for password please help me out how can I change password

Comment: Can you please help me @arjun

Comment: @sssss please go through this  [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html)  to change the password

Comment: I did the same as in this tutuorial I am getting this error name 'update_session_auth_hash' is not defined

Comment: @sssss you can post another question related to this

Comment: But now I cant as I should wait for 2 hours @arjun

Comment: Did you import `update_session_auth_hash` from `django.contrib.auth` @sss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206405/discussion-between-sssss-and-arjun).

Comment: Yes I had imported